# OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataset/subtest/Thumbs.db'"

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Trying to Plot a few images from the test set, and compare model prediction with ground truth but error occurs  "OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataset/subtest/Thumbs.db'".

Answer (score 0):

A `Thumbs.db` file is something you'll find in your filesystem as an artifact of viewing it using a gui like the mac's finder, or windows' explorer. If you're on a unix-alike OS, try running `file` on that particular file and see what it is identified as. If you're loading all the files in that particular subdir for processing with keras, you might want to just exclude this and see if that gets you past your problem. Something like

```
>>> glob.glob("*")
['f1', 'f2', 'Thumbs.db', 'f4', 'f3']
>>> filesToLoad = [f for f in glob.glob("*") if f not in "Thumbs.db"]
>>> filesToLoad
['f1', 'f2', 'f4', 'f3']
```